# Creating WPF bindings with expressions and reflection

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding

I am trying to simplify binding WPF controls to properties in my project. I would like to be able to call the method in a manner similar to:

```
MyList.Bind( x => x.ItemsSource, App.Globals.ItemManager.Items );
```

I have written an extension method that extends `DependencyObject` and correctly resolves a `DependencyProperty` from a given PropertyInfo if one exists. Now, I need to resolve the parent object from `sourceProperty` so that I can generate a path for the correct property.

My problem is, since I am passing `sourceProperty` as an object, there seems to be no way to use reflection to get the instance of the parent, nor is there a way to get the property's `PropertyInfo`. I would like to keep the arguments list as clean as possible and as close to the above example as possible, but if there is no workaround, adding arguments is fine.

Here is my current code:

```
public static class BindingExtensions
{

  public static void Bind<TControl, TProperty>(
     this TControl control,
     Expression<Func<TControl, TProperty>> controlPropertyExpression,
     object sourceProperty )
     where TControl : DependencyObject
  {
     // Get DependencyProperty of control
     var controlPropertyInfo = controlPropertyExpression.GetPropertyInfo();
     var controlDependencyProperty = GetDependencyPropertyFromProperty( controlPropertyInfo );

     if( controlDependencyProperty == null )
        throw new ArgumentException(
           $"Could not resolve DependencyProperty for '{controlPropertyInfo.Name}' " +
           $"in class {controlPropertyInfo.ReflectedType}." );

     // Determine source object and path
     // TODO:
     //   var source = {parent instance of sourceProperty}
     //   var path = {name of sourceProperty}

     // Bind

     return;
  }

  public static IEnumerable<FieldInfo> GetDependencyPropertiesFromType( Type controlType )
  {
     var properties = controlType
        .GetFields( BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public )
        .Where( x => x.FieldType == typeof( DependencyProperty ) );

     if( controlType.BaseType != null )
        properties = properties.Union( GetDependencyPropertiesFromType( controlType.BaseType ) );

     return properties;
  }

  public static FieldInfo GetDependencyPropertyFromProperty( PropertyInfo propertyInfo, Type controlType = null )
  {
     if( controlType == null )
        controlType = propertyInfo.ReflectedType;

     var property = controlType
        .GetFields( BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public )
        .FirstOrDefault( x =>
            x.FieldType == typeof( DependencyProperty ) &&
            ((DependencyProperty)x.GetValue( null )).Name == propertyInfo.Name );

     if( property == null && controlType.BaseType != null )
        return GetDependencyPropertyFromProperty( propertyInfo, controlType.BaseType );

     return property;
  }
```

}

Comment: @Clemens Yes, that is a part of the problem. I could pass in byref, but I would still need a way to use reflection to get the desired info.

Comment: What else than the name of the property do you need to create a Binding Path? Just pass `nameof(App.Globals.ItemManager.Items)` and the source object.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually simple:

```
public static void Bind(
    this DependencyObject obj, DependencyProperty property, object source, string path)
{
    BindingOperations.SetBinding(obj, property, new Binding
    {
        Source = source,
        Path = new PropertyPath(path)
    });
}
```

Usage:

```
MyList.Bind(
    ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty,
    itemManagerInstance,
    nameof(App.Globals.ItemManager.Items));
```